# Есть ли преимущества у Nginx перед связкой Nginx + Apache?

Tags: apache, nginx

Если сайт содержит динамический контент (Python, Ruby + MySQL, PostgresQL), а не только статический, будет ли выигрыш в скорости при использовании Nginx как единственного веб-сервера на выделенном сервере? И будет ли выигрыш в скорости, если база целиком в памяти (типа Redis)?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю то Python и Ruby цепляются к apache через cgi интерфейсы. Тогда не понятно зачем им лишний посредник в виде Apache.

Answer (score 0):

С таким довольно экзотическим контентом апача будет только мешать. Смело можете ставить только nginx.